# Combobox in a datagridview with a Typeconverter

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, typeconverter

I have a pretty simple class that I want so Show in a Datagridview. For one property I want to Display a Dropbox with possible selections. I thought I could accomplish this with a typeconverter but either I'm wrong with this or I don't know....

This is the class I Show in the DataGridView:

```
public class CommandlineArgument
{
    public CommandlineArgumentType ArgumentType { get; set; }
    public string ArgumentName { get; set; }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(ParameterConverter))]
    public string ArgumentValue { get; set; }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(ConditionCheckConverter))]
    public int ConditionCheck { get; set; }

    public CommandlineArgument(CommandlineArgumentType argumentType, string argumentName, string argumentValue)
    {
        ArgumentType = argumentType;
        ArgumentName = argumentName;
        ArgumentValue = argumentValue;
        ConditionCheck = 0;
    }
}
```

And thats the TypeConverter:

```
public class ConditionCheckConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public static PDSPackage CurrentlyEditedPackage;

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        string[] possibleValues = new string[1];

        possibleValues = CurrentlyEditedPackage.ConditionChecks.Select(cc => cc.Name).ToArray();

        return new StandardValuesCollection(possibleValues);
    }

    #region Convert To
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(String)) { return true; }
        return false;
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        string ccname = CurrentlyEditedPackage.ConditionChecks.Where(cc => cc.ID == Convert.ToInt32(value)).First().Name;
        return ccname;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

If I set the DatagridViewColumn to a Combobox I get an exception. If set it to a simple TextBox I dont get a Dropdown...

**Edit**

OK so this are my ConvertFrom methods:

```
public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        int CheckID = CurrentlyEditedPackage.ConditionChecks.Where(cc => cc.Name == (string) value).First().ID;
        return CheckID;
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(String)) { return true; }
        return false;
    }
```

But I doesn't help. I've set break Points in every method but it seems the only one that is called is `ConvertTo`